# JSON formatted string to String Array

Tags: java, android, json

I'm using a simple php API (that I wrote) that returns a JSON formatted string such as:

```
[["Air Fortress","5639"],["Altered Beast","6091"],["American Gladiators","6024"],["Bases Loaded II: Second Season","5975"],["Battle Tank","5944"]]
```

I now have a String that contains the JSON formatted string but need to convert it into two String arrays, one for name and one for id. Are there any quick paths to accomplishing this?

Comment: Lots of parsers to choose from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/338586/a-better-java-json-library

Comment: aw! this ain't JSON. Where're da currley braces? ...and colons?

Comment: For the record, none of these JSON libraries is going to work unless you actually emit proper JSON.  I would start there...

Comment: Interesting. I was simply using php's json_encode function to output this.

Comment: Perhaps the objects you are feeding it are wrong and this is the best it can do.  Proper JSON would be: [{"Air Fortress":"5639"},{"Altered Beast":"6091"},{"American Gladiators":"6024"},{"Bases Loaded II: Second Season":"5975"},{"Battle Tank":"5944"}]

Comment: Actually, proper JSON would probably look more like: [{"name":"Air Fortress","id":"5639"},{"name":"Altered Beast","id":"6091"},{"name":"American Gladiators","id":"6024"},{"name":"Bases Loaded II: Second Season","id":"5975"},{"name":"Battle Tank","id":"5944"}]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [org.json](http://www.json.org/java/index.html) library to convert your json string to a `JSONArray` which you can then iterate over.

For example:

```
String jsonString = "[[\"Air Fortress\",\"5639\"],[\"Altered Beast\",\"6091\"],[\"American Gladiators\",\"6024\"],[\"Bases Loaded II: Second Season\",\"5975\"],[\"Battle Tank\",\"5944\"]]";

List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> ids = new ArrayList<String>();
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(jsonString);
for(int i = 0 ; i < array.length(); i++){
    JSONArray subArray = (JSONArray)array.get(i);
    String name = (String)subArray.get(0);
    names.add(name);
    String id = (String)subArray.get(1);
    ids.add(id);
}

//to convert the lists to arrays
String[] nameArray = names.toArray(new String[0]);
String[] idArray = ids.toArray(new String[0]);
```

You can even use a regex to get the job done, although its much better to use a json library to parse json:

```
List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> ids = new ArrayList<String>();
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"(.*?)\",\"(.*?)\"") ;
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while(m.find()){
    names.add(m.group(1));
    ids.add(m.group(2));
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly and without the use or an additional library. Thank you!